# Tablet has working Voice Search but code says no speech recognition capability

Tags: android

I add internet permission to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I run this is my onCreate:

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    CanRecog=0;
    if (activities.size() != 0)
    {
        CanRecog=1;
    }
```

BUT, when code runs, it reports no capability (CanRecog=0).
What else do I have to do to be able to use speech recognition from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it was working fine.
But when I Deleted the App "Voice search" it returned a "0" value.

Have you installed this application provided from google?
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC52b2ljZXNlYXJjaCJd

Comment: Yes, now I see it does work only when Voice Search is installed and not disabled.  Thanks for trying that, I missed the correlation.